# How to I combine together different categories of observation within the same variable in R?

Tags: r, merging-data

I'm working with one categorical variable which lays out ethnicities from census data. I've already renamed the categories from 1,2,3 etc to the codebook names of the various ethnicities but some of them overlap and are really small, like a few observations each. How can I merge categories like "White&Black Caribbean", "White&Black African", "White Asian" into a single category which is just "Mixed ethnicity"

This is what I've got coded so far, I'm brand new to R as a student any help would be appreciated.

```
table(d$y11, useNA = "ifany")

d$y11<-factor(d$y11, labels = c("British","Irish","Gypsy/Irish Traveller","Any other White","White&Black Caribbean","White&Black African","White Asian","Any other mixed","Indian","Pakistani","Bangladeshi","Chinese","Any Other Asian","African","Caribbean","Any other Black","Arab","Any Other group","Prefer not to say"))
```

I tried testing with just two using `dplyr`

```
d$y11 <- combine(d$y11, name = "Mixed Ethnicity", combinations = list("Mixed Ethnicity" = "White&Black Caribbean","White&Black African"))
```

but just got a series of errors I don't understand at all.

> Error in `vec_c()`:
> ! Can't combine `..1`  and `..3` .
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> Warning message:
> `combine()` was deprecated in dplyr 1.0.0.
> ℹ Please use `vctrs::vec_c()` instead.
> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
> rlang::last_trace()
> <error/vctrs_error_ptype2>
> Error in `vec_c()`:
> ! Can't combine `..1`  and `..3` .

I also tried using Merge which didn't work either

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(d)`?

Comment: @jpsmith When I use dput(d) it's just a ton of numbers and NA which goes so long i can't even scroll to the top of it in the console

Comment: try using `dput(d[1:20,])`.

Comment: @deschen Same issue, there are almost 4000 observations over 150 variables in this dataset.

Comment: @tm575 then try making a smaller dataset that is representative of your real data and sufficient to re-create the error - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) for some tips - but it’s gonna be really difficult to help without any kind of example data, so providing that we get you much better, faster help. Good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith Sadly I can't change that, it's data I have to work with for an assignment. Thanks for trying to help though :)